# Is it bad practice to store VkSemaphores in an std::unordered_map in a synchronisation manager class?

Tags: c++, vulkan, synchronization

**Vulkan API** requires you to synchronise your rendering using [VkSemaphores](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VkSemaphore.html). When rendering a frame for example, we have to wait until the next image can be acquired from the swapchain. We also have to signal that presentation of the rendered image can begin. This is discussed by every [Vulkan tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/).

The semaphores are create during initialisation and destroyed during shutdown. In any example code I could find (Sascha Willems, official Khronos examples..), VkSemaphore are stored as a **class member** in the renderer class. I was wondering if I could abstract the problem by creating a VulkanSemaphoreManager class, which would be inherited by the renderer class. In short, this class stores the semaphores in an unordered_map with std::string (the name I gave to the semaphore) as key:

```
/// @class VulkanSynchronisationManager
/// @brief Creates and destroys Vulkan fences and semaphores.
/// Those are essential for the synchronisation of multithreaded rendering and asynchronous code in general!
/// @note Fences are mainly designed to synchronize your application itself with rendering operation,
/// whereas semaphores are used to synchronize operations within or across command queues.
class VulkanSynchronisationManager
{
    private:

        // The semaphores that our application needs.
        std::unordered_map<std::string, VkSemaphore> semaphores;


    public:

        VulkanSynchronisationManager()
        {}

        ~VulkanSynchronisationManager()
        {}

    protected:

        /// @brief Checks if a semaphore with this name already exists.
        /// @param semaphore_name The name of the semaphore.
        /// @return True if a Vulkan semaphore with this name already exists, false otherwise.
        bool does_semaphore_exist(const std::string&semaphore_name) const
        {
            std::unordered_map<std::string, VkSemaphore>::const_iterator semaphore_lookup = semaphores.find(semaphore_name);

            if(semaphore_lookup == semaphores.end())
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        /// @brief Creates a new Vulkan semaphore.
        /// @param semaphore_name The unique name of the semaphore.
        const std::optional<VkSemaphore> VulkanSynchronisationManager::create_semaphore(const VkDevice& vulkan_device, const std::string& semaphore_name) const
        {
            // First check if a Vulkan semaphore with this name already exists!
            if(does_semaphore_exist(semaphore_name))
            {
                // Error handling...
                return std::nullopt;
            }

            VkSemaphoreCreateInfo semaphore_create_info = {};

            // So far, there is nothing to fill into this structure.
            // This may change in the future!
            // https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VkSemaphoreCreateInfo.html
            semaphore_create_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SEMAPHORE_CREATE_INFO;
            semaphore_create_info.pNext = nullptr;
            semaphore_create_info.flags = 0;

            // The new Vulkan semaphore which will be created.
            VkSemaphore new_semaphore;

            VkResult result = vkCreateSemaphore(vulkan_device, &semaphore_create_info, nullptr, &new_semaphore);
            if(VK_SUCCESS != result)
            {
                vulkan_error_check(result);
                return std::nullopt;
            }

            // THIS does not work, see following text.
            semaphores.insert({semaphore_name, new_semaphore});

            return new_semaphore;
        }


        /// @brief Gets a certain semaphore by name.
        /// @param semaphore_name The name of the semaphore.
        /// @return The acquired semaphore (if existent), std::nullopt otherwise.
        const std::optional<VkSemaphore> get_semaphore(const std::string& semaphore_name) const
        {
            if(!does_semaphore_exist(semaphore_name))
            {
                // Error handling...
                return std::nullopt;
            }

            // Return the requested semaphore.
            return semaphores.at(semaphore_name);
        }


        /// @brief Destroys all existing semaphores.
        void shutdown_semaphores(const VkDevice& vulkan_device)
        {
            // Create an iterator for the unordered map.
            std::unordered_map<std::string, VkSemaphore>::const_iterator sepahore_iterator = semaphores.begin();

            // Iterate over the unordered map.
            while(sepahore_iterator != semaphores.end())
            {
                // Destroy the semaphore.
                vkDestroySemaphore(vulkan_device, sepahore_iterator->second, nullptr);

                // Move on to the next Semaphore.
                sepahore_iterator++;
            }

            // Clear the unordered map!
            semaphores.clear();
        }

};
```

This class bundles all existing semaphores and offers create and get methods. It is also responsible for destroying all semaphores during application shutdown.

**But there is a problem**: We can't insert the new VkSemaphore into the unordered_map, because Vulkan defines semaphores are nondispatchable handles.

*Is this a good idea after all?*

Thanks for you feedback, John.

Comment: Anything named "Manager" is likely to constitute a problem rather than a solution. Having said that, it isn't quite clear what your problem is. Any type is either copyable or not. If it's not copyable, you cannot pass or return it by value, alone or wrapped in `std::optional`. You can however wrap it in a (non-copyable) class of your own and use `emplace` of your container in order to create one.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: By declaring create_semaphore as a "const" member function, I was unable to modify the unordered_map.

Thanks for the advice though! Since this class is way bigger than the old approach, I will rethink it.